# XSLT Union on elements

Tags: xslt, join, union

I am a newbie. Need XSLT help:Employer can be n number. Employee can be n number. No need to find duplicate. Here is the source xml.
Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <employer name="one">
        <employee name="1"/>
        <employee name="2"/>
    </employee>
    <employer name="one">
        <employee name="1"/>
        <employee name="2"/>
    </employee>
    <employer name="two">
        <employee name="1"/>
        <employee name="2"/>
    </employee>
    <employer name="three">
        <employee name="1"/>
        <employee name="2"/>
    </employee> 
</root>
```

required output

```
<root>
    <employer name="one">
        <employee name="1"/>
        <employee name="2"/>
        <employee name="1"/>
        <employee name="2"/>
    </employee>
    <employer name="two">
        <employee name="1"/>
        <employee name="2"/>
    </employee>
    <employer name="three">
        <employee name="1"/>
        <employee name="2"/>
    </employee> 
</root>
```

Comment: I am guessing your end employee tags should be employer tags, or your XML is not valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simpler, more efficient solution use Muenchian grouping and push style.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="emp" match="employer" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <root>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/employer[
   generate-id(.) = generate-id( key('emp',@name)[1])]"/>
 </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="employer">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@* | key('emp',@name)/*" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! what if we want to sort the employer based on name (alphabetical)

Comment: Read about Muenchian grouping [here](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Once you understand it, you can apply any grouping conditions. Read about sorting [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/07/03/transform.html).

Answer (score 0):

With a fixed XML source file, this:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="employer">
            <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::employer[@name=$name])">
                <employer name="{@name}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="/root/employer[@name=$name]/employee">
                        <employee name="{@name}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </employer>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>            
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

gives you what you wanted. Or what I assume is what you want - your actual desired output isn't valid XML so I assume you didn't mean to have opening employers matching closing employees?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <employer name="one">
        <employee name="1"/>
        <employee name="2"/>
        <employee name="1"/>
        <employee name="2"/>
    </employer>
    <employer name="two">
        <employee name="1"/>
        <employee name="2"/>
    </employer>
    <employer name="three">
        <employee name="1"/>
        <employee name="2"/>
    </employer>
</root>
```